# Комбинаторика распределения очереди

Tags: python, комбинаторика

Это не учебный вопрос! Не могу решить как это сделать. У меня есть решение с особым способом заполнения таблицы, это работает но чем больше участников тем больше погрешность и решение магическое, хочется придумать надежный алгоритм. Это вопрос в прошлый раз заминусовали, распишу конкретнее. На мой взгляд задача довольно увлекательная.

Произвольная группа спортсменов выступают на соревнованиях. От 10 до 50 -ти участников. (спортивная ловля рыбы)
Соревнования проводятся в три тура. Очередность выступления спортсменов влияет на результат и определяется жеребьевкой. Каждый спортсмен вытягивает карточку с его местом в очереди на три тура.
Например, в первом туре он выступает пятым во втором третьим и в последнем девятым.
Основная задача распределить очередность так, чтобы среднее место в очереди за три тура у всех было одинаковым с допуском максимум в одно место. Как распределить очередь?

Я слабак в математике, и тем более в ее разделах, о комбинаторике узнал позавчера!
Как пытаюсь решить.

```
from itertools import permutations
    
st=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    
sred = int(sum(st)/len(st))
    
for i in permutations(st, 3):
    y = (i[0] + i[1] + i[2])/3
    if y == sred:
        print(i)
```

Вычисляю среднее место в очереди, округляю. Отбираю варианты где среднее место соответствует и уже почти придумал как отобрать нужны результат. Знаю, что это так себе решение.
Я не прошу готового решения, если есть какая-то готовая функция или адекватное решение этой проблемы, направьте меня в нужное русло!

Comment: да, примерно столько

Comment: Получается по вашему примеру, нужно составить N троек разных чисел с суммой каждой тройки равной N/2*3. То есть при 25 участниках, средняя сумма троек должна быть 12,5 * 3 = 37,5.

Comment: При 25 ти участниках средняя будет 13

Comment: Отличная задача. Считаю подходящие перестановки для нечётных `n`. Их довольно много. Например для `n = 15` перестановок с идеальным балансом `15! * 659632`. Можно будет написать довольно быстрый случайный генератор.

Comment: 271 подходящий вариант при 20-ти участниках. Первая очередь идет по списку 1.2.3...20..

Comment: Как вы считаете? 271 вариант для 20-ти участников - это очень мало.

Answer (score 3):

Вот что приходит в голову: неполное решение, но дает направление.

Их соображений симметрии среднее место находится в центре.
Сгенерируем случайное положения для первого тура. Теперь перенумеруем (или, что то же самое, переназовем) участников
так, чтоб первый участник находится на первом месте, второй на втором и так далее.
Т.е. будем их называть по местам, которые они занимают в первом туре, т.е. участник 1, это тот, кто в первом туре на 1 месте и т.д.
Теперь несколько наблюдений:

1. так как места в первом туре фиксированны, то место участника во втором туре, практически однозначно (с точностью до допуска в 1 место) определяет его место в третьем туре
2. при жеребьевке второго тура, не все места будут доступны для всех участников. Например, участник 1 не может опять получить место 1 во втором туре, так как никакое место в 3 туре не годится чтобы среднее было в средине.

Рассмотрим как можно сгенерировать номера мест `X` и `Y` для второго и третьего туров для участника номер `K`.

`(K + X + Y)/3 = N/2`

т.е. `Y = (3*N/2-K) - X`

Так как `Y>=1` и `Y<=N`, то мы можем определить из каких значений можно выбирать `X`.

```
1 <= 3*N/2-K-X => X <= 3*N/2-K-1
N >= 3*N/2-K-X => X >= N/2-K
```

Потенциально (игнорируя уже занятые места) значение может `X` может быть в диапазоне `[max(N/2-K, 1), min(3*N/2-K-1, N)]`.
Из этого диапазона и генерируем `X` и соответствующее ему `Y` исключая уже занятые.

Единственное, что неочевидно пока, не может ли получится, что для какого-то участника не удастся сгенерировать место, так как уже все будет занято. Возможно в такой ситуации придется отступать назад, т.е. при каждом выборе делать перебор с отступлением, когда все перебрали, а решения нет. Перебирать на каждом шаге можно:

1. по возможным значениям `Y` для данного выбранного `X`
2. по значениям `X` на каждом шаге (но недетерминированно, т.е выбирать случайно, но запоминать выбор, чтобы при повторной попытке брать еще неиспользованные значения)

Comment: Ваше решение неплохо работает. Пока только экспериментирую, но получается.

Answer (score 2):

Программа [fisher_table](https://github.com/StanislavVolodarskiy/fisher_table) основана на идеях [Roman Konoval](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218971/roman-konoval).

```
$ python fisher_table.py 10
Используйте '--seed 561571' чтобы воспроизвести результаты.

-----------------------------
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
-----------------------------
 9  5  3  4  6  1 10  2  8  7
10  8  3  6  7  5  2  1  4  9
 7  2  1  4  8  9  6 10  5  3
-----------------------------

Ожидаемое среднее место 5.5. Диапазон средних мест в таблице от 5.333 до 5.667.

 1:  6  8  3 : 5.667
 2:  8  7  2 : 5.667
 3:  3  3 10 : 5.333
 4:  4  9  4 : 5.667
 5:  2  6  9 : 5.667
 6:  5  4  7 : 5.333
 7: 10  5  1 : 5.333
 8:  9  2  5 : 5.333
 9:  1 10  6 : 5.667
10:  7  1  8 : 5.333
```

Если игроков 25 или меньше, строятся наиболее сбалансированные турниры: для чётных дисбаланс `1/6`, для нечётных дисбаланса нет.

Если игроков от 25 до 50, то дисбаланс не более `1/2`.

#### Основной алгоритм

Первый тур фиксируется. Для второго тура рекурсивно ищется случайная перестановка. Когда в перестановку второго тура добавляется новый участник, делается проверка что в третьем туре свободно место для соблюдения баланса: среднее место участника по всем трём турам должно быть примерно равно среднему месту в соревновании.

Если проверка не прошла, то текущая перестановка отбрасывается и продолжается поиск других вариантов.

Для нечётного числа участников алгоритм всегда находит сбалансированый турнир, в которой средние места всех участников равны.

Для чётного числа строится таблица в которой средние места участников отличаются не более чем на `1/6` от среднего места по турниру. Это лучший возможный результат.

#### Рестарты

Время поиска перестановки второго тура сильно зависит от генератора случайных чисел. Чтобы уменьшить время генерации, основной алгоритм ограничен по числу операций. Если достигнуто ограничение, а подходящая перестановка ещё не найдена, основной алгоритм перезапускается с увеличенным в два раза ограничением и другой стартовой точкой в генераторе случайных чисел.

#### Составные таблицы

Основной алгоритм с перезапуском достаточно быстро порождает таблицы для числа участников до 25. Дальше он замедляется так, что ждать непрактично. Для больших чисел таблица делится пополам, половинки строятся рекурсивно, а затем перемешиваются. Наилучшего баланса этот способ не достигает, но дисбаланс остаётся небольшим.

#### Окончательное перемешивание

До сих пор во всех решениях первый тур был упорядоченным. Чтобы сделать и его случайным, номера (но не места) всех участников случайно перемешиваются. Теперь все три тура являются совершенно случайными. На баланс такое перемешивание не влияет.

#### Производительность

Производительность основного алгоритма различается для чётных и не чётных `N`. Не знаю почему, но чётные даются тяжелее. Минимальное, среднее и максимальное времена для `N = 24`, `N = 25`:

```
 N    min    avg    max
24  0.035  0.669  5.367
25  0.032  0.045  0.203
```

Так как после 25 вступает "разделяй и властвуй", то для программы тяжелее всего даются `N = 24 * 2^k`. Шутки ради за минуту можно построить турнир на 1536 рыбаков с дисбалансом не более 12.

```
$ time python fisher_table.py --seed 887069 1536

...

Ожидаемое среднее место 768.5. Диапазон средних мест в таблице от 747.3 до 789.7.

...

real    0m59.924s
user    0m59.908s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117271/discussion-between-stanislav-volodarskiy-and--).